# c++ QPushButton signal and slot

Tags: c++, qt, signals, qpushbutton, slot

I have a problem creating a `QPushButton` and linking its signal to my slots. First, I created a class with the slot:

```
class A : public QWidget{

  public slots:
    void handleButton();

};
```

There is my `handleButton` function in the .cpp

```
void A::handleButton(int row, int col){
    m_button->setText("Example");
    // resize button
    m_button->resize(100,100);
}
```

Then I want to connect the button.

```
QObject::connect(m_button, SIGNAL(clicked()), qApp, SLOT(handleButton()));
```

But I got an error when I start the application:

```
"No such slot"
```

Comment: Is qApp an instance of class A? And also the signatures are wrong

Comment: Im new in c++ i dont know how to set correct instance.

Comment: If qApp isn't an object of class A, it hasn't that slot.

Comment: class A : public QWidget{
Q_OBJECT
public:
   A() {}


public slots:
   void handleButton(){
       m_button->setText("Example");
         // resize button
         m_button->resize(100,100);
   }

}; and got error : C:\Qt\Tools\QtCreator\bin\untitled3\windowheader.h:9: error: undefined reference to `vtable for A'

Comment: This is going nowhere, I'd suggest studying C++ first. You can't use Qt if you don't know C++ first

Comment: i need examples to know c++, my biggest problem is functions, i dont know how to use functions when buttone was clicked

Comment: You forgot to use Q_OBJECT macro in your class.

Comment: @SaZ - from his second comment looks like he didn't forget it. Looks like Marco is right, he needs to learn C++ first, he doesn't look like he is quite there yet.

Comment: Please paste your entire code. You're making so many mistakes, its difficult to explain with what you've shown

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that `qApp` is an object of class `A` (i.e. where your slot is defined).

That said, the signatures are wrong: a signal links to a slot only if the signature match

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html

> The signals and slots mechanism is type safe: The signature of a signal must match the signature of the receiving slot.

And your slot hasn't the right signature:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qabstractbutton.html#clicked

```
void QAbstractButton::clicked ( bool checked = false ) [signal]
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in this code, if you define "void handlebutton()" then you must implement void handlebutton() NOT void handlebutton(inx x, int y) this code should not even compile.

More: in QT you CAN ONLY connect SIGNALS and SLOTS with the same parameters so you can connect SIGNAL(clicked()) with SLOT(handlebutton()) but not SIGNAL(clicked() with SLOT(handleButton(int, int)).

Another problem is that connect is executed at runtime so You must compile and run before Qt can show you the error.

So a possible solution is:

define and implement the slot void handlebutton() and connect that to the signal clicked(), then define another method handleButton  (int x, int y) that you will call from inside handleButton().

I really hope that makes sense to you.

Answer (score 0):

Your class definition should look like :

```
class A : public QWidget
{
Q_OBJECT
public slots:
  void handleButton(int, int);
};
```

And you should connect it like:

```
QObject::connect(m_button, SIGNAL(clicked()),qApp, SLOT(handleButton(int a, int b)));
```

where `a` and `b` are variables for row and column.

This should work. Try understanding basic C++. :)